# Custom QML Quick 2 Control with TabBar Inside

Tags: qt, qml

I am creating a custom QML Quick 2 TabBar control in Qt 5.15. If I make a simple control (CustomTabBarSimple.qml) as

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
TabBar {
}
```

Then I can use it with

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640; height: 480
    color:"silver"

    CustomTabBarSimple
    {
        id:bar
        TabButton { text:"Button1" }
        TabButton { text:"Button2" }
    }

    StackLayout {
        anchors.top: bar.bottom
        currentIndex: bar.currentIndex
        Text {text: "First Stack"}
        Text {text: "Second Stack"}
    }
}
```

[image]

But if instead I wrap the TabBar in another control like this is no longer functions:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Rectangle
{
    default property alias contents: bar.data

    width: 300; height:50
    color: "red"

    TabBar {
        id: bar
    }
}
```

[image]

You can see I tried to use `default property alias contents: bar.data` to put the `TabButton` inside the custom control's `TabBar` but it appears that the `TabBar` no longer organizes  the buttons properly and they no longer change the `currentIndex` when clicked---likely because the `data` field is overwriting critical elements.

Is it possible to inject the `TabButton` into the proper place using a default alias? Second, how would I be able to discover this for myself from the documentation?

Comment: What happens if you add `anchors.fill: parent` after `id: bar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two problems with your code:

1. You're trying to access `currentIndex` from the TabBar, but you're not exposing that property in your CustomTabBarSimple. You can fix that by adding this:

```
property alias currentIndex: bar.currentIndex
```

2. The list of TabButtons are not direct children of the TabBar. TabBar is derived from a Container, which has a list of child objects in `contentData`. You can read about that [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-container.html#contentData-prop).

```
default property alias contents: bar.contentData
```

Comment: This is correct. However, it's not clear from the documentation link that this will function. How do you/we know this is true without requiring  expert input? Surely it's not acceptable to just go around replacing lists in containers until it works?

Comment: Yeah, the documentation doesn't describe every detail or use-case. But Qt is also open source. I actually found this answer in the source code before I located the documentation for it.